# Cannot invoke any operation required authentication even after correct log-in

Tags: java, api, soap, soapui, xtrf

I use [the XTRF API](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPI/Welcome+to+XTRF+API+Knowledge+Base) version 1.3 at URL `http://[security]/translationManagementService/PartnerWSAPI`
and SOAP UI 4.5 for simulation of client actions.

I'm able to successfully login (get no error message) but any other operations fail with an exception

> You are not authenticated or given credentials are incorrect, please re authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago (I was using a generic XTRF Web Service API, not the version for partners). As far as I remember, it was caused by something related to connection persistence.

Nevertheless, I dealt with the problem, so please check out my [XTRF API adapter class in Ruby](https://gist.github.com/3945418). It doesn't cover all methods the API offers but for me it was sufficient.

Hope it will help you somehow.

Comment: Thanks. I've fond the solution - you need to set "maintain http connection" flag so SOUP UI does not create a new session for the successive http calls.

Comment: @user1749939: feel free to post this as an answer to your own question and (possibly) earn some upvotes in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is the soultion for me:
problem description: I would like to call a website at backend, which was able to response for me with a JSON. The task was to test the JSON structure. I was not able to do it, because I always got a redirect for my login site.

solution: 
1. Go to the "Show Service Viewer" and hit the "Service Endpoints" bar. Enter the http domain and the corrent username and password. For example, I would call `"http://www.rocket.com/backend /homescreenJson"`
 than I enter `"endpont"="http://www.rocket.com` and my username/pass for the site as I would login from the browser.
2.Hit the File/Preferencies in soapUI, go to the "HTTP settings" and check in the following box: "Add authentication setting to outgoing requests".

I worked for me. 
Cheers,
Karoly